# IE7 making Galleria Fullscreen do funny things with dots navigation

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, gallery, galleria

My Galleria gallery seems to be working everywhere except in IE7. I have hacked at the code to make it fit the designer's vision, however, I've ended up with a strange space and some dots along the top of the gallery in IE7. I have tried everything to make it disappear while allowing the navigation to function.

Wondering if any clever person could look at the code and offer some suggestions?

Here is and example of the phenomenon where I'm storing the live site:

http://www.sheadavidsky.com/manu/ethan-allen.html

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you looking at it in IE 7.0.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
ul#galnav {
list-style-type:none;
}
```

to

```
ul#galnav {
list-style:none
}
```

that should do it :)

**EDIT**

addition after comments:

my testing found this issue just using IE8 in IE7 Browser mode (via developer tools). I'm not sure what version this acts as...

right so just changing the list style won't work because IE7 isn't actually applying the styles to that ul on load. It appeared to work because I edited a style (any style) of the ul after load. However, you'd have to wait until all the images were finished loading which is tricky.

In my other answer I mention how it works if you have an empty style tag. I've been fiddling for ages now and this isn't the only thing that hasn't broken. try this and see if it works for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.browser.msie && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident')== -1){
        $('head').append('<style></style>');
    }  
    $('#gallery').galleria();
});
```

That's about as dirty a fix as you could want! :)

Comment: hmmm, that might not work after all. Think it might have worked via developer tools because it forced IE7 to correctly interpret styles...

a quick and dirty fix would be to use js to add an additional style to force the same behaviour...

Comment: @Ken - I believe it was IE 7.0.6, but can reconfirm if it helps? Of course it was the client who discovered the problem! :(

@lnrbob - I will try your suggested solution of changing the list style. I live for dirty fixes - could your please explain what you mean by "use js to add an additional style to force the same behaviour" (sorry, pretty new to this)

Comment: lnrbob - I will try it at work today and test it on Explorer tonight. I can't believe you were working on it for ages (I know I've spent days on this thing)... So incredibly generous of you! Thank you so very, very much for your effort on my behalf. I'll be back as soon as I've tested it with the results. Thank you again. Hurray for the dirty fix! :)

Comment: Hi - just wanted to give an update. Have tried it out and it seems that I can't get it to load in IE7. I have only tested it using browsershots - but they all seem to come back with the loading image. I might download IE7 in the coming days and play with it in real time. But I thank you so much for your help, lnrbob. And it may actually work in real time. I'll keep you posted (and will keep you posted!).

Comment: Groovy, thx for the updates! If you are getting the loading image but not seeing the list item style then I would suspect it is working. If you've got IE8 you can use the developer tools to enable IE7 mode (different to compatibility mode) which is very accurate. Good luck!

Comment: Aha - perfect. Didn't know I could do that with the developer tools. I am going to consider this case closed. With loads of thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another answer because it is so different to my first:

**edit** removed most of answer. I thought it was to do with where your script tag was - I put it at the end of my document and it looked to be working. Unfortunately it just seemed to lessen the frequency of the issue. I've also noticed that if you use a  tag in the  you don't get the problem. Even if the style tag is empty. It is very, very weird.

btw: Doesn't seem to be the !DOCTYPE either